# Calling Parent's Constructor In JavaScript OOP

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I have created two objects:

- Mammal
- Cat

Cat extends Mammal. Both objects have constructor which takes one parameter called config. I am trying to overwrite Mammals constructor in Cat's constructor but I am getting strange results:

```
function Mammal(config) {
    this.config = config;
    console.log(this.config);
}

function Cat(config) {
    // call parent constructor
    Mammal.call(this, config);
}
Cat.prototype = new Mammal();

var felix = new Cat({
    "name": "Felix"
});
```

This prints in the console:

```
undefined fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:23
Object {name: "Felix"}
```

Why is the parent constructor called twice? And why, when it's called the first time, this.config is undefined? I am assigning the property. Could you help me fix this code?

http://jsfiddle.net/DS7zA/

Comment: you're calling it here `Cat.prototype = new Mammal();`

Comment: See the question [What is the reason to use the 'new' keyword here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here) and its answers stating that one should not…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called twice because *you* call it with `Cat.prototype = new Mammal()`.  You're creating the prototype by copying from an *instance* of `Mammal`, rather than from the "prototypical" `Mammal`.

The correct line would be:

```
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype);
```

Comment: Thanks... This prototype style inheritance is confusing me a lot. I'm not used to it yet.